# How to fill a SQL Server database in a C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, xml, winforms

I'm writing a Winforms application in C# that stores data to Xml, then sends it via e-mail. These two things are running in their basic form.

But now I'm struggling with how to put this Xml file into a SQL Server database. I know that you can store value as Xml into SQL Server. But is there a way that Xml data is stored as `int`, `varchar` etc.? Or in general a way how this is handled?

Thanks in advance!

The following is the Xml - storing function:

```
private void btnWriteCustomerToXml(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Customer[] Kunden = new Customer[5];
    Customer[0] = new Customer(1, "John", "A", 10000);
    Customer[1] = new Customer(2, "John", "B", 20000);
    Customer[2] = new Customer(3, "John", "C", 30000);
    Customer[3] = new Customer(4, "John", "D", 40000);
    Customer[4] = new Customer(5, "John", "E", 50000);

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("TestMail.xml"))
    {
       writer.WriteStartDocument();
       writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");

       foreach (Customer employee in Customer)
       {
           writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");
           writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
           writer.WriteElementString("Vorname", employee.FirstName);
           writer.WriteElementString("Nachname", employee.LastName);

           writer.WriteEndElement();
       }

       writer.WriteEndElement();
       writer.WriteEndDocument();

       string output = "XML file was successfully created!";
       MessageBox.Show(output);
   }
}
```

Comment: Create a table `Customer` with the columns `Id`(int), `Vorname` (VARCHAR), `Nachname` (VARCHAR), then insert the values into that table. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have a already a test table, named Employee, with Employee, Id, and so on. There I want to put the Xml data into it.

Comment: So the problem is how to read the data from the xml file, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The test table has columns named and ordered like the XML documents schema in the code sample above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native XQuery support in SQL Server to "shred" your XML into relational data and store it - something like this:

```
-- declare input - could be the input parameter of a stored procedure or something
DECLARE @input XML = '<Employees><Employee><ID>4040</ID><Vorname>Dieter</Vorname><Nachname>Mueller</Nachname></Employee></Employees>'

-- INSERT INTO your table
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee(ID, Vorname, Nachname)
    -- shred the incoming XML into rows of data, based on the XPath /Employees/Employee
SELECT
    XEmp.value('(ID)[1]', 'int'),
    XEmp.value('(Vorname)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    XEmp.value('(Nachname)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/Employees/Employee') AS XTbl(XEmp)
```